# How can I add custom text to Shippo generated labels?

Tags: fedex, ups, shippo

I would like to add a custom field to the shipping label generated by Shippo to identify the physical package.  Is there any way to add custom text to the shipment label using the API?

I'm specifically looking at the Shipment, Transaction Create [API call](https://goshippo.com/docs/reference#transaction-create).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to add custom fields to shipping labels. There are two parameters that can be passed to [create transaction](https://goshippo.com/docs/reference#shipment-create), when creating a Shipment which will be printed on the label.

- reference_1
- reference_2

Shippo allows the max length of the field at 50 characters, but some carriers may truncate at around 30. So print a test label.